# Unity Simple Sliding Door. Collider moving but not the actual object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to make an automatic door when the player walks close to the door it will automatically open and then close after leaving that area. I have tried it different ways with having a different object as a collision sensor to move the door to even using a box collider on the door itself but it doesn't work. The Collider will move but you will be phasing through the door after.

```
    public float maximumOpening = 3;
    public float maximumClosing = 0;
    public float movementSpeed = 1;

    bool playerIsHere;
    bool opening;

    void Start()
    {
        playerIsHere = false;
        opening = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(playerIsHere)
        {
            if (movingDoor.transform.position.x < maximumOpening)
            {
                movingDoor.transform.position += Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else
            {
                if (movingDoor.transform.position.x > maximumClosing)
                {
                    movingDoor.transform.position += -Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime;
                }
                   
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            playerIsHere = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            playerIsHere = false;
        }
    }
```

!https://imgur.com/a/C4AmoUl

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be more like the following:

```
if (playerIsHere && movingDoor.transform.position.x < maximumOpening)
{
    movingDoor.transform.position += Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime;
}
else if (movingDoor.transform.position.x > maximumClosing)
{
    movingDoor.transform.position += -Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime;             
}
```

since otherwise the door will only do anything when the player is actually in it, and otherwise do nothing, hope it helps :)

Comment: Unfortunately it still has the same problem. The collider is still moving and I can walk through the door after but the actually object/mesh just isnt moving at all.

Comment: can you update your question with a picture of your hierarchy of the objects, as well as where your script resides? might be an issue related to parent/child relationships

Comment: I updated the post with a link to 3 images, I have tried various ways but all end the same. The 2 cubes were used as sensors for the doors but I have also changed it to not use them and only the doors but the results are still the same.

Comment: this may sound like a stupid question, but i just realised you move a gameobject called movingDoor, this doesn't happen to be just the object that has the collider right?
in your hierarchy it should be the 'startDoor' object, since a reference to an object that only has half of the stuff you wanna move etc. would maybe be the cause of the issue

Comment: The startdoor was just me to organise and subcategorize each part. The actual doors are separate and meant to act on their own. But even after isolating them and removing them from the hierarchy they still do not move.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has this problem in the future, I'm pretty sure the solution is to make sure the object isn't static. This can be found on the top right of the inspector.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).